# Java Exception on FCM Flutter Notification Click

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a flutter application that receives a notification using FCM. i am able to receive the notification but once i click on the notification i get the following exception , it is to be noted that the message "show notification method called" does print showing that the click function triggered as screen also goes to ChatDetail screen but due to this exception the application stops responding and nothing gets loaded on the screen  :

D/FLTFireMsgReceiver( 8791): broadcast received for message
I/flutter ( 8791): Got a message whilst in the foreground!
I/flutter ( 8791): show notification method called
E/MainActivity onNewIntent( 8791): null
D/AndroidRuntime( 8791): Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime( 8791): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 8791): Process: com.app.appname, PID: 8791
E/AndroidRuntime( 8791): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
E/AndroidRuntime( 8791):    at com.app.appname.MainActivity.onNewIntent(MainActivity.java:504)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8791):    at android.app.Activity.performNewIntent(Activity.java:8015)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8791):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnNewIntent(Instrumentation.java:1409)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8791):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnNewIntent(Instrumentation.java:1422)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8791):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverNewIntents(ActivityThread.java:3658)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8791):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleNewIntent(ActivityThread.java:3670)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8791):    at android.app.servertransaction.NewIntentItem.execute(NewIntentItem.java:53)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8791):    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8791):    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8791):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8791):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8791):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8791):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7660)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8791):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8791):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8791):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
I/flutter ( 8791): going to new route

this is the code of main function

```
FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
  // ignore: avoid_print
   print('Got a message whilst in the foreground!');
   checkNotification(message);
});

checkNotification(RemoteMessage message) {
  // ignore: unnecessary_null_comparison
    if (message.data != null && message.data.isNotEmpty) {
    // in case of backend
    // ignore: avoid_print
        String? title=message.notification?.title;
        String? body=message.notification?.body;
        showNotification(
          title!, body!,
          message.data['isChat'].toString());
    
}

 
  void showNotification(String title, String body,String isChat) async {
      debugPrint("show notification method called");

      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin fltNotification =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

      var androiInit = const AndroidInitializationSettings
      ('mipmap/ic_launcher');

      var iosInit = const IOSInitializationSettings();

      var initSetting = InitializationSettings(android: androiInit, iOS: iosInit);

      fltNotification.initialize(initSetting,onSelectNotification: (String? payload) async {

      try{
          if(payload!=null && payload.isNotEmpty)
           {
           print("going to new route");

           Navigator.of(GlobalUtility.navState.currentContext!)
            .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>ChatScreen() ));
            }
        }catch(e)
       {

       }
    });

    var androidDetails = const AndroidNotificationDetails('1', 'channelName',
    importance: Importance.high,  priority: Priority.high);
    var iosDetails = IOSNotificationDetails(
    sound: '', presentAlert: true, presentBadge: true, presentSound: true);
    var generalNotificationDetails =
    NotificationDetails(android: androidDetails, iOS: iosDetails);

    await fltNotification.show(0, title, body, generalNotificationDetails,
    payload: 'Notification');
 }
```